# Supersized JavaScript slider add description

Tags: javascript, slider, supersized

I added description in supersized slider. It works but the div containing the description is empty when I check the code.

in index.html:

```
        <div id="slidedescription"></div>
        ....


        slides : [ // Slideshow Images
        {image : 'img1.jpg', description : '<div"><ul><li><a href="">Text</a></li></ul></div>', title : '<h3>Text</h3>', thumb : 'img1Thumb.jpg', thumbTitle : 'Text'},
        {image : 'img2.jpg', description : '<div><ul><li><a href="">Text</a></li></ul></div>', title : '<h3>Text</h3>', thumb : 'img2Thumb.jpg', thumbTitle : 'Text'}, 
        {image : 'img3.jpg', description : '<div><ul><li><a href="">Text</a></li></ul></div>', title : '<h3>Text</h3>', thumb : 'img3Thumb.jpg', thumbTitle : 'Text'}
       ]
         });
        });
```

in supersized.shutter.min.js:

```
          afterAnimation:function(){...

          if(a(vars.slide_description).length){
(api.getField("description"))?a(vars.slide_description).html(api.getField("description")):a(vars.slide_description).html("")
           }

           a.supersized.themeVars={ ...
           slide_description:"#slidedescription",
```

The problem is: I would like the output to be in div element in the HTML page result but now:

```
         <div id="slidedescription"> </div>
```

is empty and I would like the result to be:

```
        <div id="slidedescription">
        <div ><ul><li><a href="">Text</a></li></div>
        <div ><ul><li><a href="">Text</a></li></div>
        <div ><ul><li><a href="">Text</a></li></div>
        </div>
```

Is it possible to be achieved? I guess it is but would you help me with this?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the appropriate part of the following code to *theme\supersized.shutter*:

```
afterAnimation : function(){
        if (api.options.progress_bar && !vars.is_paused) theme.progressBar();
        var description = api.getField("description");
        if (typeof description != 'undefined') {
            $('#slidedescription').html(description);
        } else {
            $('#slidedescription').html('');
        }
    },
```

Note that you may also need to edit path in the file *demo.html* from

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="theme/supersized.shutter.min.js"> </ script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="theme/supersized.shutter.js"> </ script>
```

Also, you should add part above code to '_init: function ()' that description was seen after running gallery.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this but it's not working for me. Have you tried it? 

slidedescription div is still empty in demo.html's page source.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. This solution works properly. If you run *demo.html*, you need to change slide, because the 'div' for the first slide is empty (you must complete the '_init: function ()'). Make sure that you are viewing rendered code. I recommend Firebug. See also: http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/605/

Comment: Yes. When viewing rendered code it works. Question is how googlebot will see it. I thing will see it as a empty tag.

Comment: You can try this: http://www.smart-it-consulting.com/internet/google/googlebot-spoofer/index.htm

Comment: I did it already. Shows the tag empty. Not sure how reliable is this tool.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? Have a look at the source, if it is of any help: http://www.krijnen.com/opcafe.shtml

Comment: You must disclose affiliation with external links.

Comment: Linking to an external site and saying "look at the source" isn't helpful.  If it's yours, then put code samples in your answer.